# populate dropdownlist with an array

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an array      var myList = new Array();  and I have a drop down

```
@Html.DropDownList("yourList", Model.yourList).
```

How can I fill the dropdownlist using javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myList = new Array();

for (i=0; i<myList.length; i++) {
    master.options[master.options.length]=new Option(myList[i].text, myList[i].value);
}
```

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/selectcontent.shtml

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

```
var myList = new Array();
myList.push({ value: '1', text: 'item 1' });
myList.push({ value: '2', text: 'item 2' });
myList.push({ value: '3', text: 'item 3' });
$('#yourList option').remove();
$.each(myList, function () {
    $('<option/>', {
        value: this.value,
        html: this.text
    }).appendTo('#yourList');
});
```